# Oracle - NVL, cascading NVLs, and COALESCE not working as expected

Tags: oracle, nvl

I want this field `cost_total` to return `0` if it's null. But for some reason it's still returning `null` on the front end. I've tried:

```
SUM(ROUND(NVL(RAC.NL_COST, 0),2)) OVER() cost_total

NVL(SUM(ROUND(RAC.NL_COST,2)) OVER(), 0) cost_total

COALESCE(SUM(ROUND(RAC.NL_COST,2)), 0) OVER() cost_total

SUM(ROUND(COALESCE(RAC.NL_COST, 0),2)) OVER(), 0) cost_total
```

Why are these still returning `null` and not `0`?

I've also tried these to no avail:

```
NVL(SUM(ROUND(NVL(RAC.NL_COST, 0),2)), ' ') OVER() cost_total

CASE SUM(ROUND(NVL(RAC.NL_COST,0),2)) OVER() WHEN 0 THEN ' ' END cost_total
```

Comment: Some of those aren't valid, the rest appear to work. What do you see when you run those through a client like SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, or in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) - still nulls? If not then your front end, whatever that is, might be hiding zeros for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NVL(ROUND(SUM(RAC.NL_COST) OVER (), 2), 0)
```

Cheers!!